# Calabash-cucumber simulator not running same version of app as the "-cal" scheme

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

I start out with the "-cal" scheme running just like the [Calabash setup guide](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#setup-fast-track) tells me to. Then I run `cucumber` for Calabash-iOS. The simulator seems to stop and restart before executing the tests in a different (possibly cached version) of my app and the target device has changed from an iPhone 6 to running the tests in an iPhone 5s.

How can I make `cucumber` execute the tests in the already running "-cal" scheme? Or (better yet) how can I make it relaunch using the "-cal" scheme? I can see cases where relaunching would be valuable.

Below is the only code executed before the scenarios run. I know it says `.relaunch` is in there, but if I take it out then the test fails on the first step.

```
Before do |scenario|
  @calabash_launcher = Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher.new
  unless @calabash_launcher.calabash_no_launch?
    @calabash_launcher.relaunch
    @calabash_launcher.calabash_notify(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are few questions there.

1. How can I make cucumber execute the tests in the already running "-cal" scheme?
   Answer: When you build the cal target you define what target to build for and when you execute the tests you define what target to execute on.
   Build: -sdk iphonesimulator9.0
   Execute: DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 6 Plus (9.0)'
2. The simulator seems to stop and restart before executing the tests in a different (possibly cached version) of my app and the target device has changed from an iPhone 6 to running the tests in an iPhone 5s.
   Answer: Also related partly to question 1 (defining target to control what setup you test on). Besides that the app will relaunch between scenarios otherwise each scenario would be dependent on what ever else had been executed before it.
   The one thing you can toggle is if the app should be reinstalled between scenarios. This is helpful if you have some functionality that only shows/executes on first install/launch. To add support for reinstall you can add something like this to the launch.rb file in "Before do |scenario|"

   > if scenario_tags.include?('@reinstall')
   >       @calabash_launcher.reset_app_sandbox end

Comment: reset_app_jail is deprecated in 0.10.0 - please use reset_app_sandbox

Answer (score 1):

> The simulator seems to stop and restart before executing the tests

The simulator is quit and relaunched before each Scenario for stability. If we keep the simulator open, it quickly becomes unstable. See below for more details.

> (possibly cached version) of my app

This is no longer an issue starting in run-loop 1.5* which is required by Calabash 0.16.4.  [What version of Calabash are you running](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki#reporting-problems)?  If you are building from the command line and from Xcode, have a look at this project [Calabash iOS Smoke Test](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app) and specifically [this script](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/bin/xcode-build-phase/stage-CalSmoke-cal-products.sh) that stages products built by Xcode to the same directory as the command line builds.

> iPhone 6 to running the tests in an iPhone 5s.

Starting in Xcode 7.1, the default simulator is the iPhone 6. Pre Xcode 7.1, the default simulator has been the iPhone 5s.  [Lasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1165581/lasse) is correct, use the `DEVICE_TARGET` to control which simulator to run on.

> How can I make cucumber execute the tests in the already running "-cal" scheme? Or (better yet) how can I make it relaunch using the "-cal" scheme?

You don't have to relaunch between Scenarios. Relaunching will restart the simulator.  If you don't want to relaunch, you can use a custom calabash backdoor to reset your app to a good known state before each test start.  I used to do this all the time; it really speeds up the testing.  However, I abandoned this approach because it is hard to maintain and as I mentioned, the simulator becomes unstable.

> Or (better yet) how can I make it relaunch using the "-cal" scheme?

This I actually don't understand.  Have you set the APP variable?  Is another app launching?  Did you run `calabash setup` and does your app have a Watch extension?  If so, you are probably running into this problem: [`calabash setup` adds calabash.framework to Watch extension instead of the app](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/832)